# Non-numeric input check

Tags: c++

I have a piece of code here:

```
int a,b;
cout << "Enter your parameters a and b." << endl;
while(!(cin >> a >> b) || cin.get() != '\n')
{
cout << "Error. One of your parameters isn't a number. Please, input correct values." << endl;
cin.clear();
while(cin.get() != '\n');
}
```

I know this is a non-numeric input check, but I don't know how it works. Can someone tell me how it works?
May be I do not understand how flow works and this is the reason of my misunderstanding of this piece of code. :)

Comment: @Pavan sorry just realized that. In your case, when you set a variable to ```int``` and then a user inputs a non integer ```cin``` will fail. So you could read your code as "while cin fails or if cin is a new line" then display the error message.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use of

```
while(!(cin >> a >> b) || cin.get() != '\n')
```

is a bit over zealous. If your input contains whitespace characters after the numeric input, it is going to fail. Ideally, you would like it to work if the input is `"10 20   "` or just `"10 20"`. It could be

```
while(!(cin >> a >> b))
```

That quibble aside, if extraction into `a` or `b` fails, the stream, in this case `cin`, is left in an error state. After that, the line

```
cin.clear();
```

clears the error state but it still leaves the input in the stream. The line

```
while(cin.get() != '\n');
```

reads and discards the input until the newline character is encountered. After that your code is ready to read fresh input and `cin` is in a good state to process the input.

Comment: In "cin.clear ()": I do not quite understand what it means - "but it still leaves the input in the stream". When cin get failed, we can't normaly use this flow, right? And when we "clear" him, we make this flow working again in normal conditions. But after these steps, input values ​​still save in flow. To fix this, we start second cycle, which discards excess input. In finish, we have '\n', which starts out parent-cycle again. I got it right?